How to add multiple premiums to a contribution in CiviCRM without using a contribution page in WordPress?
I’m using CiviCRM with WordPress, but I don’t have a contribution page set up. Instead, I record contributions manually through the WordPress backend. I need to be able to assign multiple premiums (gifts) to a single contribution, but it seems that CiviCRM’s default functionality only allows one premium per contribution.
I’ve looked into the settings, but haven’t found an option for adding more than one premium. I’ve also explored extensions like Line Item Editor, but I’m unsure how to configure it to meet my needs since I’m not using a public-facing contribution page.
Has anyone faced this issue before, or does anyone know of an extension or workaround that allows multiple premiums for manually recorded contributions in WordPress?
